# Git status not show difference after merged pull request

Tags: git

git status not showing difference from remote branch compared to local branch.

1. From `master`, I checkout a new branch, `dev`, and then made some changes and pushed to remote/dev.
2. I did a pull request from branch `dev` to branch `master`.
3. After sucessfully merged that pull request, I switch back to `master`, and then hit `git status`.

But when I hit `git pull`, the changes are applied onto my local branch.

I expect that the out put will be "Your local branch is behind remote/master 1 commit", but It said everything is **up-to-date**.

Can someone explain this situation **why** `git status` does **not** show that there are changes from the remote?

*I know this can be a very dumb question but thanks for the patience for a newbie*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget that git, being distributed*, is working in an asynchronous fashion. You need to get the new references from the remote to use them locally with commands like `status`.

```
git fetch
```

is enough for this.

* *(thanks to phd for the correction on vocabulary)*

Comment: "get the new references"
Does this mean that from my computer, git status will compare with the "old version" of the remote branch, and not the updated one?
And ```git fetch``` will do that?

Comment: Yes exactly. Git only knows a snaptshot of the state of the remotes. If the remotes changed, you have to tell Git to manually update its snaptshot, using `git fetch`

Comment: Not asynchronous — distributed.

Comment: @phd can you clarify "distributed" meaning for me please? :)

Comment: It means "without a central server". You always work with your local repository and from time to time synchronize the local repository with remote one(s).

Answer (score 2):

As @RomainValeri said, a `git fetch` would have updated your remotes' snaptshot to see the new commits in `master`.

However, by running `git pull` you got these changes locally (as you said: "But when I hit git pull, the changes are applied onto my local branch."), so your master is not behind anymore.

So if you just wanted to update your remotes, `git fetch` (or `git remote update`, same) is what you want; if you wanted to update your remotes, and update your local branch with the remote's extra commits, `git pull` was what you wanted.